# if (url != null) Not work

Tags: android, android-intent

as I can make a difference if "url" has information or not. and created as I do not do well. It does not work

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = bundle.getString("url");

    if (url != null) {
        emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
        emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play.  More can be found at
        //https://archive.org/details/more_animation
        emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not url found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: you mean to say it is going inside if block even for null value for url?

Comment: Whats the desired behaviour and what is the actual behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(url != null)
  if(!url.isEmpty())
```

Also when retreiving items from a bundle, a simple `if(bundle.getString("url") != null)` will also help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
```

This will ensure that a String.Empty value is also not present, which is not the same as a string being null.  In other words:

```
String s = null;
```

is not the same as:

```
String s = String.Empty;
```

Comment: Error:(63, 20) error: cannot find symbol method IsNullOrEmpty(String)    I receive this error

Comment: Try importing `com.google.common.base.Strings`

Comment: not work. and now error Error:(12, 30) error: package com.google.common.base does not exist.    Error:(63, 20) error: cannot find symbol method IsNullOrEmpty(String)

Comment: You'll need to add the jar to your project.  A good HOW-TO is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864214/installing-an-external-java-package

Comment: Your git source for this package is:  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Strings.java