# How to install Packages in java?

Tags: java, github, neural-network, deep-learning

I am just starting to learn neural networks. I picked my self a book called into to neural networks using java.  I found the package  the author uses in the book on github, but I am unsure on how to install it so I can use it!

Please help me, on how to get this package in my system! I am so stuck!

Here is the link to the github page, where I found the [package](https://github.com/jeffheaton/jeffheaton-book-code/blob/master/JavaIntroNeuralNetworkEdition2/src/com/heatonresearch/book/introneuralnet/neural/matrix/Matrix.java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing an external java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864214/installing-an-external-java-package)

Answer (score 0):

The jar is available inside the dist folder. Click here to download   https://github.com/jeffheaton/jeffheaton-book-code/commit/61c061f875c7b83d5048cef36471299e488c4cab
Add them in your classpath